# C# Selenium Can't Locate Hidden Element written in Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, webdriver, hover

I am trying to use Xpath or anything to locate the element `<span _ngcontent-c19=""> ACME Nursing </span>`

I've tried a lot of different ways to moveToElement using actions, and a lot of other ways, but I just can't make the hover and click happen.  I've tried waits as well.  I get the following error no matter what I try:

**Listed below is the code containing the hidden element I'm trying to locate:**

```html
<acme-role-facility _ngcontent-c2="" class="ng-tns-c2-1" _nghost-c20="">
  <li _ngcontent-c20="" class="header-item show dropdown" ngbdropdown=""><a _ngcontent-c20="" aria-haspopup="true" class="dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle" href="javascript:void(0)" id="roleFacilityDropdown" ngbdropdowntoggle="" aria-expanded="true"><span _ngcontent-c20="" class="block m-t-xs" id="roleFacilityName"><span _ngcontent-c20="">ACME Nursing - </span></span><span _ngcontent-c20="" class="block"><span _ngcontent-c20="">Nursing Admissions</span><b _ngcontent-c20="" class="caret"></b></span></a>
    <aht-navigation
      _ngcontent-c20="" aria-labelledby="roleFacilityDropdown" ngbdropdownmenu="" _nghost-c19="" class="dropdown-menu show" x-placement="bottom-left" style="top: 52px; left: 0px;">
      <perfect-scrollbar _ngcontent-c19="" class="nav-facility-container">
        <div style="position: static;" class="ps">
          <div class="ps-content">
            <!---->
            <div _ngcontent-c19="" class="animated fadeInDown light ng-star-inserted" style="">
              <!---->
              <ul _ngcontent-c19="" class="nav navbar-nav ng-star-inserted">
                <!---->
                <li _ngcontent-c19="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                  <!----><a _ngcontent-c19="" href="javascript:void(0)" class="active parent-menu dropdown-item ng-star-inserted"><span _ngcontent-c19=""> ACME Nursing </span><i _ngcontent-c19="" class="chevronMargin fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                </li>
                <li _ngcontent-c19="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                  <!----><a _ngcontent-c19="" href="javascript:void(0)" class="parent-menu dropdown-item ng-star-inserted"><span _ngcontent-c19=""> Dees Nursing &amp; Rehabilitation Center </span><i _ngcontent-c19="" class="chevronMargin fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                </li>
                <li _ngcontent-c19="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                  <!----><a _ngcontent-c19="" href="javascript:void(0)" class="parent-menu dropdown-item ng-star-inserted"><span _ngcontent-c19=""> Rehab and Healthcare </span><i _ngcontent-c19="" class="chevronMargin fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                </li>
                <li _ngcontent-c19="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                  <!----><a _ngcontent-c19="" href="javascript:void(0)" class="parent-menu dropdown-item ng-star-inserted"><span _ngcontent-c19=""> Nursing and Rehab Center </span><i _ngcontent-c19="" class="chevronMargin fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                </li>
                <li _ngcontent-c19="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                  <!----><a _ngcontent-c19="" href="javascript:void(0)" class="parent-menu dropdown-item ng-star-inserted"><span _ngcontent-c19=""> Nursing and Rehab Center </span><i _ngcontent-c19="" class="chevronMargin fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                </li>
                <li _ngcontent-c19="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                  <!----><a _ngcontent-c19="" href="javascript:void(0)" class="parent-menu dropdown-item ng-star-inserted"><span _ngcontent-c19=""> Care Nursing &amp; Rehabilitation Ctr </span><i _ngcontent-c19="" class="chevronMargin fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                </li>
                <li _ngcontent-c19="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                  <!----><a _ngcontent-c19="" href="javascript:void(0)" class="parent-menu dropdown-item ng-star-inserted"><span _ngcontent-c19="">  Nursing and Rehab Center </span><i _ngcontent-c19="" class="chevronMargin fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                </li>
                <li _ngcontent-c19="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                  <!----><a _ngcontent-c19="" href="javascript:void(0)" class="parent-menu dropdown-item ng-star-inserted"><span _ngcontent-c19=""> Management Firm  </span><i _ngcontent-c19="" class="chevronMargin fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!---->
          <div class="ps__rail-x" style="left: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
            <div class="ps__thumb-x" tabindex="0" style="left: 0px; width: 0px;"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="ps__rail-y" style="top: 0px; right: 0px;">
            <div class="ps__thumb-y" tabindex="0" style="top: 0px; height: 0px;"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </perfect-scrollbar>
      <!---->
      </aht-navigation>
  </li>
</acme-role-facility>
```

Here is the error I receive:

```
**Unhandled Exception: OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":".//span[starts-with(@id,'ACME Nursing')]"}
  (Session info: chrome=72.0.3626.109)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628402 (536cd7adbad73a3783fdc2cab92ab2ba7ec361e1),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElementById(String id)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.By.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<Id>b__0(ISearchContext context)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElement(ISearchContext context)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(By by)
   at AHT.Browser.FacilityRoleSelect() in C:\Users\che7592\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\AHT\AHT\Program.cs:line 72
   at AHT.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\che7592\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\AHT\AHT\Program.cs:line 33**
```

Comment: As you mentioned _make the hover and click happen_ there are two elements in the play. One element to hover over and the other to be clicked. You need to help us to identify the two elements so the contributors can be able to help you with the execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no element with your selector `.//span[starts-with(@id,'ACME Nursing')]`.

You want to get element with `ACME Nursing` text and selector for that is  `//span[normalize-space(.)='ACME Nursing']`, where `.` is text and `normalize-space` remove whitespaces.

Or: `//span[normalize-space(.)='ACME Nursing' and @_ngcontent-c19]`